# Opencv3 Error : Contours is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv3.0, image-recognition

> I am trying to match individual shape image within group of shape
>   image. I am able to find the contours but then its not able to match the shapes
>   from group of shapes image.
>
> This is the error I am facing:-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-83126d2189ca> in <module>()
     36         closest_contour = []
     37 
---> 38 cv2.drawContours(target,[closest_contour], -1, (0,255,0), 3)
     39 cv2.imshow('Output',target)
     40 cv2.waitKey()

TypeError: contours is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

**Below is the code:**

```
    template = cv2.imread('shape_match/star.png',0)
#template = cv2.cvtColor(template,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Template',template)
cv2.waitKey()

#load the target image with the shapes we're trying to match
target = cv2.imread('shape_match/matchshapes.jpg')
target_gray = cv2.cvtColor(target,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold both images first before using cv2.findContours
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(template,127, 255, 0)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(target_gray, 127, 255, 0)

# Find contours in template
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# we need to sort the contours by area so that we can remove the largest
#contours which is the image outline
sorted_contours = sorted(contours,key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

# we extract the second largest contour which will be our template contour
template_contour = contours[1]

# Extract contours from second target image
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh2,cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
    # Iterate through each contour in the target image and 
    # use cv2.matchShapes tocompare contour shapes
    match = cv2.matchShapes(template_contour,c,1,0.0)
    print(match)
    # if the match value is  less than 0.15 we
    if match <0.15:
        closest_contour = c
    else:
        closest_contour = []

cv2.drawContours(target,[closest_contour], -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Output',target)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am beginner in computer vision.kindly help me with this.

Comment: Just checkout whether if condition is satisfying or not. If it is not satisfying, then closest_counter will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is that closest contour is taking the value of an empty list causing the function to error. It looks to me like you want to break out of your for loop once you find a contour that meets your criteria so try this:

```
closest_contour = None
for c in contours:
    # Iterate through each contour in the target image and 
    # use cv2.matchShapes tocompare contour shapes
    match = cv2.matchShapes(template_contour,c,1,0.0)
    print(match)
    # if the match value is  less than 0.15 we
    if match <0.15:
        closest_contour = c
        break

if closest_contour is not None:
    cv2.drawContours(target,[closest_contour], -1, (0,255,0), 3)
else:
    print("No closest contour found")

cv2.imshow('Output',target)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It helps with this images but as i change shapes of image and run it again it gives same error.

Comment: See my edit, you shouldn't try to draw the contour if there is no contour found within your match criteria